# Expand and collapse rows using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a form with different sections. I do not want to use either a Command button or a Toggle button (their look is ugly) and since this is for clients I want it to be user friendly. Anyway so basically I want to build a macro that when they click on the shape it will collapse the unnecessary rows and expand the right rows.

So far this is what I was able to find... but it only applies to a command button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Me.CommandButton1
        If .Caption = "Initial Request" Then
            .Caption = "Hide Rows"
            Rows("12:20").Hidden = False
        Else
            .Caption = "Initial Request"
            Rows("12:200").Hidden = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

This works perfectly... but, is there a way to transform this so that it can be added to a Module and therefore assigned to a shape?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: All `shapes` in Excel can be assigned a macro. Just right-click on a shape (arrow, rectangle, balloon, picture, etc.) and then select `Assign Macro...` from the menu.

Comment: Yes but if I assign this macro it does not work. it gives me the error: Compile error: Invalid Use of ME Keyword. That's why I need a way to modify this macro so that I can assign it to a shape.

Comment: and if I simply hide the With Me.Command Button1 and End With it gives me the error Invalid or unqualified references. It highlights the .Caption information. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a shape, say a `Rectangle` and assign it a macro with this equivalent code to yours:

```
Sub Rectangle2_Click()
    With Sheet3.Shapes("rectangle 2").TextFrame2.TextRange
        If .Text = "Initial Request" Then
            .Text = "Hide Rows"
            sheet3.Rows("12:20").Hidden = False
        Else
            .Text = "Initial Request"
            sheet3.Rows("12:20").Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Obviously in this example I added a rectangle shape to `Sheet3` and it got the name "rectangle 2". You should adjust these names to your case.

Comment: thanks, I can't seem to find where the name "rectangle 2" can be changed. I tried Properties but with no success. Any idea?

Comment: Forget it I found it sorry about that. this is wonderful it works like a charm!!! thanks

Comment: Hey @ValS [if you find this answer solved your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please consider marking it as the accepted answer. It helps both you and the person who helped you :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cloud_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

If ws.Shapes("Cloud 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Initial Request" Then
    ws.Shapes("Cloud 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Hide rows"
    ws.Rows("12:20").Hidden = False
Else
    ws.Shapes("Cloud 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Initial Request"
    ws.Rows("12:20").Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

I sure hope that the following screen-cast will explain the rest.

[image]

Comment: thanks that one works as well :-) I like the video, it helps for newbees like :-)

Comment: I salute your effort :)